# How to extract constants using IDApython?

Tags: python, ida, reversing

I am working on the problem that extracts constant numbers and constant strings using IDApython.

It seems that I can use

```
idautil.Strings()
```

to extract constant strings. But how about constant numbers?

Could anyone give me some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Constant numbers are often directly encoded into the assembler code. Therefore you have to walk through all the assembler code and check them for constants.

Comment: @Robert,thank you for replying. However, how can I distinguish 8 in the assembler code of "#define A 8" from that of "int b=8;" ?

Comment: Why distinguish both cases 8 is 8, no matter where and how it is used. Anyway in IDA you will not find `#define A 8" `.

Comment: @Robert, yeah, hmmmm, I mean that "A" will be replaced as 8("mov esi, 8") and the assembler code of "int b=8;" may be looked like "mov dword [var_44h], 8". How can I know that 8 in "int b=8;" is not a constant number?  Of course variable b's value can be any number.

Comment: @Robert, Oh wait, do I mix the meaning of constant in C language and Assembly language?

Comment: Yes. But you have neither C not assembly language in IDA, just the disassembled commands.

Comment: @Robert,Ok, thank you Robert, I think I should have a good look at the paper and find out what the meaning of "numeric constants" is.